# Escape character (\n) for new line in PHP7 is not working on my web server?

Tags: newline, php-7

When I am testing the following code

```
    s$stringOne="This is what the \n escape characters are \n in it";
    echo $stringOne;

    $strong3="testing the escape characters  $100 's  \n  $stringOne ";nippet it doesn't show on new line
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

It most likely does work correctly. However, if you're viewing the result in a browser, it will be interpreted as HTML, and HTML treats newlines in text just like spaces, so you won't see those newlines outside of the page source code.

If you want a line break in HTML, you'll need to use a `<br>` element. They can be used like this:

```
$stringOne = "This is what the <br>\n escape characters are <br>\n in it";
echo $stringOne;
```

You can also make PHP add `<br>` elements for you with the [`nl2br`](https://php.net/nl2br) function, e.g.:

```
$stringOne = "This is what the \n escape characters are \n in it";
echo nl2br($stringOne);
```

Another option in HTML is to put your text inside a `<pre>` element, which makes the browser show newlines and other spaces as they appear in the source code. For example:

```
$stringOne = "<pre>This is what the \n escape characters are \n in it</pre>";
echo $stringOne;
```

If your output isn't intended as HTML and you actually meant it as plain text, you need to tell the browser that with `header('Content-Type: plain/text,charset=UTF-8');` at the top of your PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: plain/text,charset=UTF-8');
$stringOne = "This is what the \n escape characters are \n in it";
echo $stringOne;
```

Comment: I was looking for PHP_EOL, I can't see it in your answer. It is not working in my browser, is this because of php7 or something else?

Comment: PHP_EOL is just an alias for `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` depending on the platform, but it's not really relevant to _this_ question

Comment: Well, it's been quite a time. I don't even remember why I asked that. :)